# Git, SourceTree, VisualStudio and corrupted .cpp files

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, github, atlassian-sourcetree

Been working in C++ using Git (via SourceTree) for version control.

My .cpp files will randomly become seemingly corrupted when I pull the project as shown below:
[image]

Github still has the correct version of the file and even selecting the 'Open After' option in SourceTree shows me the file unaffected:
[image]

The fact that Git and Github both have no problem showing me the file suggests to me it's a Visual Studio issue but I don't know.

One thing to also note is that SourceTree can't seem to display some of my .cpp files, and just treats them like binary files (but I'm not sure if this is related or not):
[image]

It's not a massive issue since I can just copy the code from Github, but it happens almost every time I pull so it's rather annoying. Any help solving this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Both the major version and which update you are running would be important. Is this a public repository on GitHub? If so, could you share the repo URL? Are you performing the pull via the command line, or via the Git integration inside of Visual Studio? If you are pull via the command, the version of Git you are running might be interesting.

Comment: @jamill Originally I was running Visual Studio Community, but I'm now running Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Ver. 15.5.6 and it's still happening. This is actually on an entirely new install of windows, new copy of Git, SourceTree and all Visual Studio components. The pulls are done via the SourceTree interface, Visual Studio recognises that it's a Git repo but I don't interact with it through that. Unfortunately the repo is private as it contains my dissertation work.

Answer (score 0):

No solution but things that you could check:

- what is the version of git? Old versions <2.0 on Windows had a bug like that. Upgrade to the last versions that are quite good
- verify that your files are encoded in utf8
- that git don't touch you files when committing ('autocrlf' at false)

Comment: I've tried all these things to no avail. My verison of git is 2.16.1, all my files are in utf8, autocrlf is false.